# In firfox 91.4.0esr (64-bit) version entered url is triggers one more time in background after sometime

Tags: angular, firefox, spring-saml

In firefox 91.4.0esr (64-bit) I am trying to access angular app url like `<appbaseurl>/app?token=test` which checks cookie in browser if session not exists it calls spring saml url `<servicebaseurl>/saml/login?token=test`. after which service routes to idp and idp authenticates the token passed.once token is validated user will be routed to angular app again.

After this while the user is working which I have observed in saml tracer is that the same url which user accessed for launching the app `<appbaseurl>/app?token=test` is triggered one more time in background(in browser debug window network tab that request is not there).

As browser sends the same request twice after sometime user gets concurrent session logout(as only one user can login at a time as per our idp configuration).
But in private window it works fine.

Is there anything in app which I need to fix?

example code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  // Check if user is authenticated
  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    // authentication logic here
    return false;
  }

  // Redirect to login page on backend server
  redirectToLogin(): void {
    const loginUrl = '<backendurl>/saml/login';
    window.location.href = loginUrl;
  }

}


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

- 

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Note:**

```
1. same things works fine in private window.
2. same thing works fine in other versions.
```